# android keycode :KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH

Tags: android

hi i have edittext with imeoption actionsearch ,when i click search icon in virtual keyboard i need to invoke a function, i have override onKeydown but i won't get controll when i press search ,  what i do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ed1.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH){
            System.out.println("Search pressed.........");
        }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
search_edit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("The key pressed onkeylistenere is having code: "+keyCode);
                    System.out.println("The key pressed onkeylistenere is having event: "+event);

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

try this & press "search" get the keycode & use

Comment: @hotveryspicy : your code is working ,but the problem is it work twice that  is for key press and release ,so i used setoneditaction listener ,it work fine  :don't feel bad, am not mark your answer as true ,i think my answer is more accurate