# android key listener doesn't respond to numbers

Tags: android, numbers, android-edittext, numeric, keylistener

Has anyone else found that the key listener does not respond when numbers are pressed on keyboard or virtual keypad?

I used a tutorial *(broken link to whyandroid removed)*
and noticed that the only time the calculate button is available is if I press a non-numeric button when in the text box in order to activate the key listener. When pressing the numbers (at the top of the keyboard or on the virtual keypad) it does not initiate the key listener (proven in debug mode). This is not helpful when the user is only suppose to be entering numbers in the text field!

I could not find any information when googling on this topic.

KeyListener code:

```
private OnKeyListener mKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

       switch (v.getId()) {
       case R.id.txtAmount:
       case R.id.txtPeople:
           btnCalculate.setEnabled(txtAmount.getText().length() > 0
                   && txtPeople.getText().length() > 0);
           return true;
       case R.id.txtTipOther:
           btnCalculate.setEnabled(txtAmount.getText().length() > 0
                   && txtPeople.getText().length() > 0
                   && txtTipOther.getText().length() > 0);
           return true;
       }
       return false;
       }

   };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
[android keycode :KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815286/android-keycode-keyevent-keycode-search/5815335#5815335)